# Keycloak SSO Idle Token Refresh

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I am using keycloak from ReactKeycloakProvider, and running into issues with SSO idle refreshing itself.

Here is my initialization of keycloak

```
<ReactKeycloakProvider
    authClient = {keycloak}
    initOptions={{
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        checkLoginIframe: true,
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html'
    }}>
        {children}
</ReactKeycloakProvider>
```

After logging in and waiting for keycloak to say it is idle, I then call `keycloak.login()` and it just logs in instead of being idle. I have accounted for the 2 min buffer when testing this.

Any ideas why keycloak is logging in using the Session after idle should have terminated it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. There is a setting in ReactKeycloakProvider `autoRefreshToken`. Here is the updated setting passed on init.

```
<ReactKeycloakProvider
    authClient = {keycloak}
    autoRefreshToken = {false}
    initOptions={{
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        checkLoginIframe: true,
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html'
}}>
    {children}
</ReactKeycloakProvider>
```